# Tkinter conditional display from previous page's checkBoxes/checkVars values

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on an GUI using tkinter and I am encountering an issue.

I want the user to be able :

1. To select within page 'sensors_history_homepage' an arbitrary number of columns from checkbuttons (1 per column name),
2. Then when clicking a button, a new page 'sensors_custom_history' pops up, displaying some stuff for each selected column.

Please find below the minimal reproducible example :

```
import tkinter as tk
import configparser, pickle

class UI_demo:

  def __init__(self, master=None):
        """
        # Load config_back.ini parameters
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('setup_front.ini')
        self.output_folder = config['DEFAULT']['path_to_output_folder']
        print("config_front.ini file was successfully loaded ! \n")
        
        # Load in-scope columns
        with open(self.output_folder+"headers_inscope", 'rb') as f:
            self.columns = pickle.load(f)
        """
        self.columns = ["Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5"] # Simple sample as the actual dataset is private
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("1650x1000")
        self.master.state('zoomed')
        
        self.initHomePageUI()

  def initHomePageUI(self):

        self.master.title("Homepage")
        
        # Some stuff....
        
        # Menu buttons
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        frame1.pack(side="top", fill="both", pady=20, expand=True)        
        
        but3 = tk.Button(frame1, text="History", font=('Courier',12), 
                         bd=3, width=36, command = self.sensors_history_homepage)
        but3.pack(side="top", pady=12)

  def sensors_history_homepage(self):
        
        # Open new window
        window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        window.title("Sensors selection")
        window.state('zoomed')
        
        # Top empty frame
        top_frame = tk.Frame(window, height=80)
        top_frame.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        # Page header
        title0 = tk.Label(window, borderwidth=1, text="Please select sensor(s) you wish to consult")
        title0.config(font=('Courier',14))
        title0.pack(side='top')
        
        # List of sensors as check-buttons (10 sensors per column as in real-case I have 200+ sensors to display)
        frame0 = tk.Frame(window, borderwidth=1)
        frame0.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        l_frames = []
        l_checkvar = []
        l_checkb = []
        
        for i in range(int(len(self.columns)/10)):
            
            l_frames = l_frames + [tk.Frame(frame0, borderwidth=1)]
            l_frames[i].pack(side='left')
            
            l_checkvar = l_checkvar +[tk.BooleanVar(master=window) for l in range(10)]
            
            l_checkb = l_checkb + [tk.Checkbutton(l_frames[i], text=self.columns[10*i+l], variable=l_checkvar[10*i+l],
                                                  onvalue=True, offvalue=False, height=2, width=10) for l in range(10)]
            
            for j in range(10*i,10*i+9):
                
                l_checkb[j].pack(side='top')
                l_checkb[j].toggle()
        
        tmp_residual = int(len(self.columns)%10)
        
        if not tmp_residual==0:
           
            i = int(len(self.columns)/10)
            
            l_checkvar += [tk.BooleanVar(master=window) for l in range(10*i,10*i+tmp_residual)]
            
            l_frames += [tk.Frame(frame0, borderwidth=1)]
            l_frames[i].pack(side='left')
            
            l_checkb += [tk.Checkbutton(l_frames[i], text=self.columns[10*i+l], variable=l_checkvar[10*i+l], 
                                                  onvalue=True, offvalue=False, height=2, width=10) for l in range(0,tmp_residual)]
            
            for l in range(0,tmp_residual):
                l_checkb[10*i+l].pack(side='top')
                l_checkb[10*i+l].toggle()
                
        
        # Check all / Uncheck all buttons
        def check_all():
            self.checkvars = [x.set(True) for x in self.checkvars]
        
        def uncheck_all():
            self.checkvars = [x.set(False) for x in self.checkvars]
        
        frame1 = tk.Frame(window, borderwidth=1)
        frame1.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        but_ca = tk.Button(frame1, text="Check all", font=('Courier',10), bd=3,
                           command=check_all)
        but_ca.pack(side='left', padx=5)
        
        but_ua = tk.Button(frame1, text="Uncheck all", font=('Courier',10), bd=3,
                           command=uncheck_all)
        but_ua.pack(side='left', padx=5)
        
        self.checkvars = l_checkvar
        
        # Button to display selected sensors' signal history
        refresh_frame = tk.Frame(window, borderwidth=1)
        refresh_frame.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        
        refresh_but = tk.Button(refresh_frame, text="Display \n for selected sensors", font=('Courier',12), 
                         bd=3, width=30, command=self.sensors_custom_history)
        refresh_but.pack(side='top')
        
  def sensors_custom_history(self):
      
        # Open new window
        window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        window.title("Display of...")
        window.geometry("1500x970")
        window.state('zoomed')
        
        # Page header
        title0 = tk.Label(window, borderwidth=1, text="Sensors history")
        title0.config(font=('Courier',14))
        title0.pack(side='top')
        
        # List of previously selected sensors 
        l_cols = []
        l_checkvalues = list(map(lambda x: x.get(), self.checkvars))
        
        for i in range(len(l_checkvalues)):
            if l_checkvalues[i]==True:
                l_cols = l_cols + [self.columns[i]]
        
        # Some display on the page....

        # Debugging console display
        print("checkvars : length = "+str(len(l_checkvalues))+", nb of true = "+str(sum(l_checkvalues))+'\n')
        print(l_checkvalues)
        print('\n'+"columns selected : length = "+str(len(l_cols))+'\n')
        print(l_cols)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = UI_demo(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

My issue is regarding the "passing" of the checkVar values from the 'sensors_history_homepage' page to the 'sensors_custom_history' page :

1. It seems that no matter which CheckBoxes are selected in 'sensors_history_homepage', the print from 'sensors_custom_history' give the same results.
2. Trying to fetch the checkVars values from the 2nd page gives the following error :

```
File "<ipython-input-3-8b450e7f0e91>", line 149, in sensors_custom_history
    l_checkvalues = list(map(lambda x: x.get(), self.checkvars))
File "<ipython-input-3-8b450e7f0e91>", line 149, in <lambda>
  l_checkvalues = list(map(lambda x: x.get(), self.checkvars))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am wondering how to properly pass the checkVars values to the 'sensors_custom_history' page in order to display only the information the user selected in previous 'sensors_history_homepage'.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This may not be the entire problem, but your `check_all()`/`uncheck_all()` functions are destroying `self.checkvars`, by assigning a list of `None`s back to it.  List comprehensions are not appropriate for simply doing something to each item in a list, their purpose is producing a *new list*.

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, as a matter of fact it seems to be the entire problem. If I launch the UI and select from the list without using `check_al()`and `uncheck_all()` buttons, I get the expected result.
Hence, how could I check/uncheck all checkBoxes with 2 buttons without re-writing over their associated checkVars ?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Simply getting rid of the assignments to `self.checkvars` in those two functions would fix them, but you'd still be uselessly generating that list of `None`s.  The proper way to write something like that is to use two lines: `for x in self.checkvars:` / `x.set(True)`